# Is there a danger of up-voting someone too much?

Tags: discussion, voting, flagging, serial-voting, up-votes

Every now and then, I recognise someone I know on this site who I didn't notice earlier.  Unbeknownst to them, I go through their questions/answers (expecting they will be of above-average interest to me) and might up-vote a whole lot of them.

> **Question**: The system has been set up to detect mass down-voting of a user's questions/answers (and the down-votes may be undone).  Does a similar thing happen for up-voting?

Comment: Although the system might revoke these, I always encourage you to upvote good answers and questions. When the system undoes voting, it does so without any moderator interaction (moderators are essentially blind to who voted on what question, always). But vote vote vote!

Comment: Oh wow! I am not the only one who behaves in this manner! Since there's already been an accepted answer, I suggest that you avoid going hog wild. 10 up votes in an hour for one user is definitely the sort of thing that would trip a flag, as described below. I usually amble around a bit, look at the user's SE-wide activity, and only up vote what I can understand (with confidence) and find worthy. I've never had a problem with being flagged for serial up votes on such occasions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes. Mass up-voting of a particular user's question/answer by another user also gets revoked automatically. (I did the same to a user sometime back. I think I up-voted around $10$ of his/her answer within a period of an hour. It got revoked within a day.)

Comment: Ouch!  Well, thanks for letting me (and the community) know.

Answer (score 11):

If you feel that a particular answer has taught you something new and you would like to reward the user, you can set a bounty, even for 50 points.

The bounty will not be reversed automatically, like serial voting, and in addition it transcends the daily reputation cap, which means that *more* votes will be effective. If you want to upvote a user and endow them with more reputation there is little point to do so if the user already exceeded the daily 200.